# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: IntercomEvents

Tags: react-native, referenceerror, intercom

I've just upgraded from `react-native-intercom` to `@intercom/intercom-react-native`. I've managed to get the intercom working, but am struggling with this piece of code from their [docs](https://developers.intercom.com/installing-intercom/docs/react-native-configuration).

```js
Intercom.getUnreadConversationCount()

...

useEffect(() => {
    const countListener = Intercom.addEventListener(
      IntercomEvents.IntercomUnreadCountDidChange,
      (response) => {
        setCount(response.count as number);
      }
    );

    return () => {
      countListener.remove();
    };
  }, []);
```

In particular, I get the error

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: IntercomEvents.

Is anybody else seeing this?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, ok, I've found the solution to this. In order to run the code correctly, you also need to import IntercomEvents, as follows:

```js
import Intercom, { IntercomEvents } from "@intercom/intercom-react-native"
```